# How to get the current top of the stack from the UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

Here is a UIViewController where a UINavigationController has been created:

```
class Main_ProfileViewController: UIViewController { 

    var ProfileNavigationController = UINavigationController()

    buildProfileNavigationController()

    func buildProfileNavigationController() {
        let RootViewController = BlankViewController200()
        ProfileNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: RootViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(ProfileNavigationController.view)
    }

}
```

And here is the main container class with the navigation controller delegate to get the current top of the stack:

```
class MainContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    var currentTop: UIViewController?

}

extension MainContainerViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        currentTop = viewController
        print(currentTop)
    }

}
```

However, nothing is ever printed to the console. How is this achieved?

Comment: do you want to get the top view controller?

Comment: @SaurabhJain Yes, the current top view controller in the stack.

Comment: there are another method, so that you can get the top view controller

Comment: This delegate is called every time a new controller is pushed so isn't this the preferred method?

Comment: When you push or pop in navigation controller then this delegate method called

Comment: let arrayVCS = self.navigationController?.viewControllers! as NSArray can give you the the array of all the controllers in the stack. Please see if this can help.

Answer (score 0):

For getting top viewController you can use this code:

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```

Comment: Why am I not using the built-in UINavigationController delegate that is called every time a new controller is pushed to the top of the stack?